# Search Specific Value in Gmail Header Using API

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-workspace

I want to get ids of messages that do not have abc.com in their DKI domain.

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=info.abc.com
```

Currently, we can only perform an exact search like

```
replyto:noreply@xyz.com
```

but we can not do partial searching that we have in the subject or in the body?

Comment: Yes it is not possible to do a partial search with other domain. But you might want to consider this solution https://support.google.com/mail/thread/6668962?hl=en. It basically filter the mails that is received from outside your organization

Comment: You may also file a feature request using https://issuetracker.google.com/